# can you store the create view result from SHOW CREATE VIEW in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL stored procedure and I am trying to copy all views from one DB to another.  I have manage to get a list of the views to be copied but I am unsure how to create the view in the new DB.  I am currently trying the SHOW CREATE VIEW command and I can see the result of running the command:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW detailview
```

How can I store the value of the column 'Create View' into  a variable within the store procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the values from SHOW CREATE VIEW and pass them to stored procedure using SQL language. MySQL doesn't allow it.

But you can try to do it in your application (php, c#, ...). Read all values you need (CREATE VIEW statements), and execute them.